# Saving multiple webhooks data into a file with a time interval with expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webhooks

I'm trying to build a webhook catcher  that catches multiple webhooks with arrays of objects within a certain amount of time(say 3 minutes) and saves all the data in a single json array.

The overall idea is to concat multiple webhooks with object arrays into a single array with a timeout of 3 minutes( after the time elapsed the webhook should continue to listen to new incoming data), and then send the object array to another function that will sort and post it.

I'm using the function below to catch and concat all the data into single array, however I'm having trouble with setting a time interval.

```js
fs.writeFileSync('webhook_arr.json', '[]', function (err, file) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
var data_arr = [];

var wh = app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(' Webhook received!');

  let reqbody = JSON.parse(req.body);
  console.log("request body objects: " + JSON.stringify(reqbody.data.length));


  data_arr =   [ ...data_arr, ...reqbody.data ];
  console.log("data array length: " + data_arr.length);
  fs.writeFileSync('webhoook_input.json', JSON.stringify(data_arr), function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log('error', err);
  });

  console.log(data_arr);
  res.sendStatus(200);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

if it can be saved during the request you can do simple time comparison, something like this:

```
let date = new Date().getTime();

if (new Date().getTime() - date >= 1000 * 60 * 3 && data_arr.length > 0) {
    saveTofile(data_arr);
    data_arr = [];
}
```

Or you can set just setInterval():

```
setInterval(() => {
    if (data_arr.length > 0) {
        saveTofile(data_arr);
        data_arr = [];
    }
}, 1000 * 60 * 3 )
```

Comment: setInterval should be set on the app.post function or on the middleware ?

Comment: @ksilla it cannot be in app.post, must be outside it but in place where have access to data_arr